How to reconstruct periodic signal from numpy.fft.fft using sines, cosines, and a Fourier design matrix?
I'm creating a periodic time-domain signal by summing a series of sine waves with some amplitude, frequency, and phase. After performing a FFT with NumPy (reference), I construct a vector of the Fourier coefficients in the sine/cosine basis. Then I define a Fourier design matrix with sine/cosine elements evaluated at the different times and frequencies as shown below,

where T is the period of the signal, t are the time samples, and Nf is the number of Fourier modes used. I should be able to reconstruct the original signal by multiplying column vector of sine/cosine Fourier coefficients by the Fourier design matrix.
Here is the code I have to implement this:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Function to create a real-valued signal with non-integer time samples
def create_signal(t, freq_components):
    signal = np.zeros(len(t))
    for amplitude, freq, phase in freq_components:
        signal += amplitude * np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq * t + phase)
    return signal

# Perform FFT and get the sine and cosine coefficients
def compute_fourier_coefficients(signal):
    N = len(signal)
    fft_result = np.fft.fft(signal)
    
    # Initialize arrays for cosine and sine coefficients
    cosine_coeffs = np.zeros(N // 2 + 1)
    sine_coeffs = np.zeros(N // 2 + 1)
    
    # Compute coefficients
    for k in range(1, N // 2 + 1):
        cosine_coeffs[k] = (2 / N) * fft_result[k].real
        sine_coeffs[k] = -(2 / N) * fft_result[k].imag
    
    # DC component (mean)
    cosine_coeffs[0] = np.mean(signal)
    
    return cosine_coeffs, sine_coeffs

# Create the Fourier design matrix with non-integer time samples
def create_fourier_design_matrix(t, num_modes, T):
    N = len(t)
    design_matrix = np.zeros((N, 2 * num_modes))
    
    for k in range(1, num_modes + 1):
        design_matrix[:, 2 * (k - 1)] = np.cos(2 * np.pi * k * t / T)
        design_matrix[:, 2 * (k - 1) + 1] = np.sin(2 * np.pi * k * t / T)
    
    return design_matrix

# Reconstruct the signal from the Fourier coefficients
def reconstruct_signal_from_design_matrix(fourier_design_matrix, cosine_coeffs, sine_coeffs):
    num_modes = len(cosine_coeffs) - 1
    coeffs = np.zeros(2 * num_modes)
    coeffs[0::2] = cosine_coeffs[1:]
    coeffs[1::2] = sine_coeffs[1:]
    reconstructed_signal = fourier_design_matrix @ coeffs
    reconstructed_signal += cosine_coeffs[0]  # Add DC component to match original signal mean
    return reconstructed_signal

# Parameters
N = 1024  # Number of samples
t = np.linspace(5000, 12000, N)  # Non-integer time samples from 5000 to 12000
T = t[-1] - t[0]  # Total duration
# Frequency components should correspond to actual frequencies in the signal
freq_components = [(1.0, 5 / T, 0), (0.5, 10 / T, np.pi/4), (0.2, 20 / T, np.pi/2)]  # (amplitude, frequency, phase)

# Create the original signal
original_signal = create_signal(t, freq_components)

# Compute Fourier coefficients
cosine_coeffs, sine_coeffs = compute_fourier_coefficients(original_signal)

# Create Fourier design matrix
num_modes = N // 2
fourier_design_matrix = create_fourier_design_matrix(t, num_modes, T)

# Reconstruct the signal
reconstructed_signal = reconstruct_signal_from_design_matrix(fourier_design_matrix, cosine_coeffs, sine_coeffs)


# Plot the original and reconstructed signals
plt.plot(t, original_signal, label='Original Signal')
plt.plot(t, reconstructed_signal, label='Reconstructed Signal', linestyle='dashed')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('signal')
plt.show()

However, the reconstructed signal is offset in time from the original signal as shown below

What is going wrong?

Looks to me like a sign convention issue with the isin(wt) components so that your waveform is shifted along by half a cycle (IE change to -np.sin(2pikt/T)). BTW why are you doing this when you already have the periodic signal in the time domain to start with? Computing the entire matrix of sin and cos coefficients is very expensive and slow for large N. Incidentally FFT is only good for this if the signal that you present to it is truly periodic across the end boundary of the array. Any discontinuity at the end of the array and you will have problems.

You introduced the phase difference in the line:
t = np.linspace(5000, 12000, N)

Change this to:
t = np.linspace(0, 7000, N)

and you will be fine. The DFT is tacitly premised on the start coordinate being 0.

